# How to get information(Model, Serial, ...) of Samsung Gear S3 smartwatch?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am trying to get the information(Model number, Serial, ...) in a tizen application running on Gear S3. On the watch, this information can be found - Settings -> Gear info -> About Device

Is there any method or API to get the value in a tizen application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tizen'SystemInfo' API provides such System Information.You can check SystemInfo Web API documentations:

[SystemInfo API: Tip&Tech](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/system-information-api-guide)

[SystemInfo Web API Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/device-settings-and-systems/system-information)

[SystemInfo Web API References](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.2/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/wearable/tizen/systeminfo.html)

Here's a sample code to get model number and software version. You can check in the API references for the specific properties you are looking for (only if they are available).

```
 function onSuccessCallbackBuild(info) {
         alert("Model:" + info.model+ "\n"+"Manufacture:"+ info.manufacturer+ "\n"+"Build:"+ info.buildVersion);
     }

 function onErrorCallback(error) {
         alert("Not supported: " + error.message);
     }

 tizen.systeminfo.getPropertyValue("BUILD", onSuccessCallbackBuild, onErrorCallback);
```

There is also Tizen native API for System Information. May have a look If you are going for a Tizen Native application.

[SystemInfo Native API Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/device-settings-and-systems/system-information)

[SystemInfo Native API References](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.2/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__SYSTEM__SYSTEM__INFO__MODULE.html)

Comment: Hi Armaan-Ul-Islam, Thanks for your support. I will try.